# A simple way for expressing the arctan2 in paper?

Tags: trigonometry

In my paper, I determine the `theta_p` from the `mean_y` and `mean_x`, ranging from [0, 2pi). That is

[image]

However, this a bit too verbose for such a simple idea. Is there any better way that I can write it in a paper?

I find a `more compact` version in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2, it still feels very verbose.

[image]

Comment: "a bit too verbose for such a simple idea." - consider mentioning your "simple idea" in words, and we can prolly help you with a matching mathematical formulation.

Comment: @J.M. Perhaps get the angle from (x, y)?

Comment: Then `atan2()` really is the simplest you can get, my friend. It's practically an idiom at this point.

Comment: Then can I write `atan2` directly in my paper? Or with citations?

Comment: Sure, "where `atan2(y,x)` gives the angle $\theta$ in polar coordinates" or something like it.

Answer (score 2):

You could try
$$\text{atan2}(y,x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac y{x+\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right),&y\ne0\lor x>0\\
\pi,&y=0\land x<0\\
\text{undefined},&y=0\land x=0\end{array}\right.$$
**EDIT**: My solution above followed Wikipedia's (and the normal) definition with the range of $(-\pi,\pi]$. Examining your definition more carefully, your range is $[0,2\pi)$ so that looks more like
$$\text{atan2}(y,x)=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\pi+2\tan^{-1}\left(\frac y{x-\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right),&y\ne0\lor x<0\\
0,&y=0\land x>0\\
\text{undefined},&y=0\land x=0\end{array}\right.$$

Comment: But I'm afraid this is harder to understand with a simple glance?

Comment: You could simply say that your $\text{atan2}(y,x)$ is the same as the standard $\pi-\text{atan2}(y,-x)$. That way all a read need do is figure out where you put the branch cut.